# getBoundingClientRect not returning sizing info iOS8

Tags: javascript, uiwebview, ios8

In a `UIWebView` in iOS, there are divs in an `iframe` that gets queried. For each div, I extract attributes and the top, bottom, left, right, width, height of the div.

```
<div class="x" id="1234" data-type="web"
     data-href="http://x.com/foo?bar=z"></div>
```

JS:

```
var divs = iframe['contentDocument'].getElementsByClassName('x');
return [].map.call(divs, function (div) {
    return _.extend(div.getBoundingClientRect(), {
      id: div['id'],
      href: div['dataset']['href'],
      type:  div['dataset']['type']
});
```

This works fine in iOS 6 and iOS 7 and all data is present including the sizing data from getBoundingClientRect. In iOS 8 the `getBoundingClientRect` is only returning an empty object, yet the div's id and dataset fields are returned. Any ideas why or how to get it working?

Comment: I'm having issues with this too, I've just submitted a bug report to apple. This was working in previous versions of iOS 8.

Comment: @PhilippeSabourin try swapping the params in extend. it seems to work that way. _.extend({
      'id': div['id'],
      'href': div['dataset']['href'],
      'type:  div['dataset']['type']
}, div.getBoundingClientRect());

Comment: I wasn't using your code exactly, this is broken for me as well: document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].getBoundingClientRect()

Comment: Are you trying to JSON.stringify the result by chance? I was and ClientRect returned by getBoundingClientRect is circular and not handled well anymore. Extending a non-circular json object as a workaround helped my situation.

Comment: I was using JSON.stringify.... I had to do the extend trick 2 times in my code: JSON.stringify({bodyRect: $.extend({'bug':'useless'},$('.frame')[0].getBoundingClientRect()),elementRect:$.extend({'bug':'useless'},$('[data-exhibit=%d]')[0].getBoundingClientRect())}); You should post your solution as an answer and I'll upvote it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found out that you must not access the properties of the returned `ClientRect` in a dictionary-like-manner:

```js
document.querySelector("#link").getBoundingClientRect()["left"] // Does not work
document.querySelector("#link").getBoundingClientRect().left    // Does work
```

Or, as an immediately executed function:

```js
(function() {
  var element = document.querySelector('#link');
  var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  return { left: rect.left, top: rect.top, width: rect.width, height: rect.height }; 
})()
```

This implementation works for me both in iOS 7 and iOS 8.